# Mapbox Map Kotlin annotation plugin - required 'style', found 'style?'

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, symbols

I really need some advice on this.

Im trying to get the Mapbox Annotation Plugin to work. 
on https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation/ it says to create a SymbolManager like this:

```
// create symbol manager object
val symbolManager = SymbolManager(mapView, mapboxMap)
```

On "SymbolManager" im getting the error:
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

- (MapView, MapboxMap, Style) defined in com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.annotation.SymbolManager
- (MapView, MapboxMap, Style, CoreElementProvider, String?, GeoJsonOptions?, DraggableAnnotationController!) defined in com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.annotation.SymbolManager
- (MapView, MapboxMap, Style, String?) defined in com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.annotation.SymbolManager
- (MapView, MapboxMap, Style, String?, GeoJsonOptions?) defined in com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.annotation.SymbolManager

It seems as if i need a style object. 
So i deciced to go like this :

```
override fun onMapReady(mapboxMap: MapboxMap) {
        this.map = mapboxMap
        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {

            //this here is just to be able to see your own location on the android device, it should not interfer with the symbol manager (i guess)
            enableLocationComponent(it)

            //get the current Stly (MAPBOX_STREETS)
            val style: Style = mapboxMap.style!!

            //Create Symbol Manager, it requires a style object so i'm using the one i created above, documentation actually doenst say any style object is needed here
            val symbolManager = SymbolManager(CellMap!!, mapboxMap, style)

            //non data driven properties
            symbolManager.iconAllowOverlap = true

            //create symbol to test the symbol function
            val symbolOptions: SymbolOptions = SymbolOptions()
                .withLatLng( LatLng(37.410, -122.084))
                .withIconImage("res/mipmap/ic_launcher/ic_launcher.png")
                .withIconSize(1.3f)
                .withSymbolSortKey(10.0f)
                .withDraggable(true)
            symbol = symbolManager.create(symbolOptions)
        }    
    }
```

I'm using an icon that was already given by android studio.
Still it's not showing any symbol on the map when i open it, and i don't understand why.
The code i am using i got from the java code here:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/annotation/SymbolActivity.java
I just had to 'convert' it to kotlin, which i did myself. Not sure if i did anything wrong with it, but at least im not getting any errors.

Thanks in advance. I hope i provided every piece of information required to assist me. If not i would be very happy to provide it. Also i tried to format everything the correct way, sorry if i missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Add your bitmap resource like this

```
mapboxMap.getStyle().addImage("my-marker",bitmap)
```

Then pass the same string to

```
.withIconImage("my-marker")
```